# passing a stringstream to a function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to pass a stringstream, from a file, to a function. When I'm calling the template function, I'm getting an error: no matching function for call to 'toFile'. I verified that the life is opened and the data has passed from it to the stringstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T1>
void toFile(string type, int NumOfElements, stringstream& ss){

   T1* myArray = new T1[NumOfElements];  // declaring new array to store the elements
   int value;

   for(int i = 0; i < NumOfElements; i++){ // store the elements in the array
       ss >> value;
       myArray[i] = value;
       cout << myArray[i] << " ";
   }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ifstream ins;
   ofstream outs;
   string strg1;
   string type;
   int NumOfElements = 0;
   stringstream inputString;

   ins.open(argv[1]);

   if(argc<1) {
        cout << "please provide the file path." << endl;
            exit(1);
    }


   while (getline(ins, strg1)){ // reading  line from the file
   inputString.clear(); // clearing the inputString before reading a new line
   inputString << strg1;

   inputString >> type ;        // reading 1st element in a row
   inputString >> NumOfElements; // reading 2nd element in a row

   toFile(type, NumOfElements, inputString);
  }
   ins.close();
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file contains lines like these: int 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 or 
char 6 h a y K o z

Comment: Why would you name a stream `inputString`? o.O

Comment: Put that detail _in the question_. Comments are temporary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toFile` is a function template, so it can only be called with a template parameter.  Sometimes function templates can deduce their parameters from their arguments, but since `T1` isn't used in your argument list, there's no way to deduce it.  You'll need to explicitly provide the template argument instead, for example:

```
toFile<int>(type, NumOfElements, inputString);
```

Comment: The solve the problem but only for the first line in my file. the next line is: char 6 h a y K o z, meaning type char, 6 elements, and the elements to store at an array

Comment: @SHR: Then put your calls in a switch statement depending on the type you need.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a template argument for `toFile`, so the template cannot be instantiated.

Thus, no function `toFile<T>` (which would have been an instantiation of said template) exists.

The argument cannot be deduced automatically because none of the function arguments have anything to do with it.